# c++ member initialization list completeness

Tags: c++, list, initialization, member

must class member initialization lists in c++ be complete? or can they simply initialize one or two of the member data in a class?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

They don't have to be complete. You can leave out base classes and non-[POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) class types that are default constructible, POD-types however will be left uninitialized.
Obviously constant members and references *have* to be initialized in the member initialization list.

Comment: is there a difference between what the member initialization list does and what initializing variables through default constructors does, other than efficiency?

Comment: @alpha: What do you mean "through the default constructor"? At this stage, you shouldn't really be worried about efficiency anyway but correctness of code.

Comment: @alpha: If you mean explicit vs. implicit default construction/initialization - there is only a difference for those types that would be left uninitialized.

Comment: @alphacentauri: The question make so sense. You can use initialization list in default constructor. Your question suggest that they are mutually exclusive, which is not true.

Comment: i was wondering or not initializing data in a default ctor has the same effect as using a member initialization list.  I remember hearing somewhere that initialization and assignemt are not the same thing

Comment: Do you mean *assign values* in the constructor body? You can use a member initialization list (MIL) in the constructor: `foo::foo() : MLI {}`.

Comment: @alpha: I think an example of what you mean would help.

Answer (score 1):

`int` does have a constructor, see Stroustrup The C++ Programming Language section 6.2.8

```
int j = int();
```

This initializes j to 0 (The value of an explicit use of the constructor for a built-in type is 0 converted to that type, thus int() is another way of writing 0.
Default constructors for built-in types are important so that templates can invoke default constructors without worry, even for built in types.

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't have to be complete - any members which aren't specified in it will be default-constructed (this includes any base classes).

Obviously, any members which aren't default-constructible must be explicitly initialised. And a small gotcha - types like integers or floats etc will not be initialised, so their initial value will be undefined.

Comment: Not true in general. Members that aren't specified will be processed (or not) in accordance with their specific rules. For example, members of type `int` will be left uninitialized. To say that they will be "default-constructed" is incorrect. You can't "construct" and `int`. It has no constructor.